# Parse PFQuery doesNotMatchKey: inQuery:

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

I am trying to fetch all `Box` objects from my Parse database. While doing this, I want to filter out the ones I have pinned to be deleted. I did this by pinning them:

`[object pinWithName:@"DeleteObjectPin"];`

I simply create another query which gets all objects pinned to be deleted and then make my main query not include those results.

```
PFQuery *mainQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Box"];

PFQuery *subQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Box"];
[subQuery fromPinWithName:@"DeleteObjectPin"];

[mainQuery whereKey:@"objectId" doesNotMatchKey:@"objectId" inQuery:subQuery];
```

Make sense? Get objects which don't match objects in this sub query, meaning the ones that I pinned to delete.

So why is it that when I add this `whereKey` constraints to my main query, do I get zero results? Note, for example, I have 5 objects without this pin name and 2 with it. Regardless of what the ratio is, I get no results.

Can I expect a query like this to work?

Comment: can you plz post the code were you pin the object and the code where you fetch all the objects in the "subQuery"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not start your object with a default value every time you create it, and change it like you do.

Once you want to fetch all the objects without @"DeleteObjectPin" you just:

PFQuery *objectQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Box"];
[objectQuery whereKey: equalTo:];

// then fetch all the objects with block or something

Comment: While this doesn't exactly achieve the approach I wanted, I can see this would work in its place. My issue with your suggestion would be having to add and track this attribute on every class I need to achieve this on which is a pain, but it would work!

Comment: In its place, I have solved the issue, simply by fetching all of the objects using a `PFQuery` and `fromPinWithName:`. Then in my main query don't include those objects. I was originally concerned this would cause two server requests, but it turns out, it only pings the server once, as the `fromPinWithName:` method, get data from the local database. Solving my issue.